# The entry point method could not be loaded

Tags: 64-bit, archlinux, wine

I'm trying to execute iExplorer with wine in ArchLinux (x64).
It's for accessed at my iPod.

But when I enter: `wine iExplorer`.
I have this error:

> The entry point method could not be loaded.

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 4):

You're likely to be missing *[.NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download)*, you can install it as follow:

```
apt-get install winetricks
winetricks dotnet46
```

Answer (score 1):

did you install wine_gecko (Wine's built-in replacement for Microsoft's Internet Explorer)?

```
pacman -Syy
pacman -S wine_gecko
```

[wine_gecko arch package page](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=wine_gecko)

Comment: I'm trying to execute iExplorer for Ipod, Ipad... no Internet Exploer

Comment: look in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: there is also an app `gtkpod` that might be helpful to you